# ProxyPass with Gollum wiki

Tags: apache-httpd

I'm trying to run [Gollum](https://github.com/github/gollum/), a wiki that uses git, on a Debian server for personal use. Launching it without any command line options makes it listen to to `http://localhost:4567`, which I can access just fine, even from PCs on the same LAN (with the right IP).

However, I want to access it through `http://x.x.x.x/gollum`, so I added these lines to `apache2.conf`:

```
ProxyPass /gollum/ http://localhost:4567/
ProxyPassReverse http://localhost:4567 /gollum/
```

Accessing `http://x.x.x.x/gollum/home` (/home is the main page of the app) works, but it'll only show the html of the page, without css, javascript, images, or even the links working. The `error.log` file is full of errors like these, just to give an example:

```
File does not exist: /usr/share/javascript/editor, referer: http://192.168.1.68/gollum/home
File does not exist: /usr/share/javascript/gollum.js, referer: http://192.168.1.68/gollum/home
```

In the html of the page, if I inspect it with Firefox, the links for the items above are all written, for example, like this: `src="/javascript/gollum.js"`.

If I write the url of the files directly, `http://localhost/javascript/gollum/gollum.js`, the right file will load.

So, how can I make the site work from `http://localhost/gollum/`? Am I doing the redirection wrong or can this be because gollum doesn't support being deployed this way?

Answer (score 1):

I was just trying this out today.
As I found out, two things were required to be able to host gollum on, say, www.mydom.com/wiki.

First, configure an apache vhost for the wiki.

```
<VirtualHost *:80>
    ServerName www.mydom.com
    ProxyPass /wiki http://localhost:4567/wiki
    ProxyPassReverse /wiki http://localhost:4567/wiki
</VirtualHost>
```

I know that the .../wiki in the ProxyPass looks odd, but bear with me for a couple of lines!

Following, run gollum in the following way:

```
~$ gollum --host 127.0.0.1 --port 4567 --base-path wiki
```

Setting the host/port is not necessary if you are using the defaults (at this stage I was mixing and matching!).
The `--base-path` statement will tell Gollum to run from /wiki instead of /.

This *seems* to be working, I have only had it up for five or so minutes. Create, view, delete, etc, etc all work. The only issue I am having is with icons not showing correctly at the "all" listing.

edit: codeblock incorrectly formatted (markdown).

Comment: Just as an FYI in case you _did_ try this before.```--base-path``` seemed to be broken 2 or so months ago (from the Issues section on the git repo). So if you did give it a try before and it didn't work, give it another go. It seems to be working now.